# Not allowed to use waitforseconds in my if statement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, wait

I'm currently playing around with some animations for my game but I've come across an issue I can't seem to find the solution to. What I'm trying to do is make my script wait for 0.05s before continuing.

I've tried with `threadsleep`, which didn't work any better. I was told it wasn't ideal for this situation anyway, so now I'm trying `waitforseconds`, which I can't get to work at all.

```
public class AttackMoves : MonoBehaviour {

int belastende = 0;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("j")) 
    {
        print("HighAttack1 Initiated");
        belastende++;

         if(belastende=1)    // Begynd tilbagesving
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
            yield WaitForSeconds (0.05);
            belastende++;
        }

         if(belastende=2)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
            yield WaitForSeconds (0.05);
            belastende++;
        }

         if(belastende=3)
        {
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
            yield WaitForSeconds (0.05);
            belastende++;
        }
```

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/350721/c-yield-waitforseconds.html

Answer (score 0):

the return type of your update method must be `IEnumerator` if you want to use a  yield return.

```
// Update is called once per frame
IEnumerator Update () {

if (Input.GetKeyDown("j")) 
{
    print("HighAttack1 Initiated");
    belastende++;

     if(belastende=1)    // Begynd tilbagesving
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
        yield return WaitForSeconds (0.05);
        belastende++;
    }

    ...
}
```

By the way, handling asynchronicity is pretty awful in Unity. Enumerators for asynchronous operations are only a hack, and a difficult to figure out and use at that. I hope that one day we will see `Task` or `IObservable`-based asynchronicity in the engine...

Answer (score 0):

**WaitForSeconds** is only meant to work in **coroutine** function. To create a coroutine function, change void to IEnumerator.

It is `yield return new WaifForSeconds` **Not** `yield return.`

Also, I noticed a **big problem** you made that new programmers usually make. If you want to compare values, you need to use two equal signs instead of one. So change belastende = `1,belastende = 2 and belastende = 3` **to** `belastende == 1,belastende == 2,belastende ==3.` in the if statement.

So your code would look like something like this:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class delete : MonoBehaviour
{

```
int belastende = 0;
bool running = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    StartCoroutine (CheckInput ()); //Call the fucntion from the start
}

// Update is called once per frame
IEnumerator CheckInput ()
{
    if (running) {
        yield break;// If this is called again while already running, exit
    } else {
        running = true;
    }

    while (running) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown ("j")) {
            print ("HighAttack1 Initiated");
            belastende++;

            if (belastende == 1) {    // Begynd tilbagesving
                transform.Rotate (0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.05f);
                belastende++;
            }

            if (belastende == 2) {
                transform.Rotate (0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.05f);
                belastende++;
            }

            if (belastende == 3) {
                transform.Rotate (0, 0, -25); // Vil have sværet til at svinge tilbage til z-125 --> wait 0.1s --> rotate lidt mere
                yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.05f);
                belastende++;
            }
        }
        yield return null; //Wait so that unity doesnt freeze
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Im currently trying this out but when running the script there is no errors but nothing happens when i press "j" either, not even the Attack initiated message in console